# Placing onPause in Activity where it handles variable

Tags: android

I am in need of a little help with placing `onPause` in my code. This is my `onPause` method I was suggested earlier today

```
@Override public void onPause() { 
if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) { 
alertDialog.dismiss(); super.onPause(); } }
```

My activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

 final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref_name", 0);
    boolean disappear = settings.getBoolean("installed", false);

    if (disappear == false) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
        alertDialog.setMessage("dialog");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            settings.edit().putBoolean("installed", true).commit();

                }
            });

 AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
 alertDialog.show();   



            final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typo1);
            Button check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check1);
            check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {       
                if (editText.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Congrats!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

When I try to put my `onPause` under `alertDialog.show();` I get an syntax error under `void` that says "syntax error on token "void", @ expected" and when I try to put at the bottom with `onStop` it doesn't recognize `alertDialog` I do not know how to solve this problem and I have been at it for hours and do know how to solve it. So can help me place `onPause` in the proper place in my activity

logcat

```
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.theproblemsolver/com.theproblemsolver.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onPause()
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5210)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1226)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3002)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2971)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1245)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-13 03:10:37.496: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have [to read about OOP first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), to know what are methods, variables, fields, and what is the syntax for each element of your code.

Let's get back to your question:

```
When I try to put my onPause under alertDialog.show(); I get an syntax error under void that says "syntax error on token "void"
```

That's really normal, as you said, it's a syntax error, meaning that you haven't respected the normal syntax to define a method : [Defining methods in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

```
when I try to put at the bottom with onStop it doesn't recognize alertDialog
```

That's again really normal, you have declared your `alertDialog` as a local variable, meaning that you won't get it out of that method. : [Variable Scopes in Java](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

```
So can help me place onPause in the proper place in my activity
```

You can place it after/before any other method in that class, for instance, after your on stop :

```
/*  .... */

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}

@Override 
public void onPause() { 
    if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) { 
        alertDialog.dismiss(); super.onPause(); 
    } 
}
```

**Edit :**

This line of your log :

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.theproblemsolver/com.theproblemsolver.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onPause()
```

means that you have to call a method called `super()` in your `onPause`. [Read this to understand what does it do !](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html), and correct your `onPause` like this :

```
@Override 
public void onPause() { 
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
    if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) { 
        alertDialog.dismiss(); super.onPause(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you my `onPause` is in the right place now but now seem to cause a few problems. Whenever I press the home button on the android device or whenever my application loads another activity my application crashes because of my `onPause`. Would you like to me help me solve this problem? if so I will post my logcat. If not I understand

Comment: just posted it in the question

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
@Override public void onPause() { 
          super.onPause();
          if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) 
          { 
           alertDialog.dismiss();  
          } }
```